# Integrating Admob SDK with Mopub on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob, mopub

I'm trying to Integrate the Admob SDK into my Android app. This is so Admob will work with Mopub. Mopub's [instructions](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Integrating-Third-Party-Ad-Networks) link to Google's integration [instructions](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start#creating_a_new_project). I'm confused by Google's instructions since I'm not using Android Studio or Gradle.

What is the Eclipse equivalent to the section starting with "Once Google Play services is installed"? I think this is making the build process aware of a Google Play Services jar file. I don't know enough about Eclipse, the Java Build Path, etc to determine the Eclipse equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/integrating-new-google-admob-banner-interstitial-ads/

This link will help you integrate google play services into your eclipse project for the purpose of displaying AdMob ads. But as far as I see in google search, there is no official tutorial related to eclipse integration of AdMob now.(It has been replaced by Android Studio tutorial) I guess they might be focusing more towards asking developers to use Android Studio. So I think, we might have to make transition soon.